# How to return a value that is not expected by method

Tags: java, binary-tree, option-type

It is the part of Main method

```
    System.out.println(node.getNode(3)); //in the end i have to get Optional[3]
    System.out.println(node.getNode(7)); // in the end I have to get Optional[7]
```

And I have the methods

```
public Optional<Node> getNode(Integer value) {
    return getNodeHelper(this, value);
}

public Optional<Node> getNodeHelper(Node note, Integer value) {
    if (note.value.equals(value)) {
        return Optional.of(note);
    } else if (note.value < value) {
        return getNodeHelper(note.right, value);
    } else if (note.value < value) {
        return getNodeHelper(note.left, value);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

The questions is next, how I should to do return, that in the end to get Optional[3] or Optional[7] not some Optional[ee.ttu.iti0202.tree.Node@6615435c]

This line I cannot change (The task from University)

```
public Optional<Node> getNodeHelper(Node note, Integer value)
```

Variable that i use in this class are:

```
private Integer value;
Node left;
Node right;
```

It would be simpler return type `Optional<Integer>` then I could write return `Optional.of(note.value)` and that is all, but I have to use `Optional<Node>`.

The lecturer advised to use override, but i have not understood how to do it .

Comment: What do you mean with `Optional<3>`? If you want to return an `Optional<Integer>`, you need to return an `Optional<Integer>`. Or do you just want the console output to change? In this case, just override [`public String toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: You seem to be having a XY problem. You are basically asking how to return an Optional holding the value that you give the method. That makes no sense. Please try to rephrase your question with a problem, not with the solution you believe you need.

Answer (score 1):

In the `getNode()` method map the returned  `Optional<Node>`  to `Optional<Integer>` :

```
public Optional<Integer> getNode(Integer value) {
    return getNodeHelper(this, value).map(Node::getValue);
}
```

Comment: From OP: "*It would be simpler return type `Optional<Integer>` then I could write `return Optional.of(note.value)` and that's all, but I have to use `Optional<Node>`*"

Comment: This cannot be changed `public Optional<Node> getNodeHelper(Node note, Integer value)` but  nothing is said about the caller : `getNode() `.

Answer (score 0):

In the Node class can you write toString() Method?? and return the value of Integer in it ?

If you write the toString() method then it will not return Optional[ee.ttu.iti0202.tree.Node@6615435c] value instead it will return what you return in the toString() method.

```
//overriding the toString() method 
public String toString(){ 
  return value.toString();  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! exactly what I need